# Run vagrant up with VirtualBox gives "VirtualBox is complaining that the installation is incomplete" in GitHub Codespaces

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant, github

I am trying to spin up a vagrant VM to use as the working environment.

When I try to spin up the machine, it keeps throwing me the error:

```bsh
The provider 'virtualbox' that was requested to back the machine
'default' is reporting that it isn't usable on this system. The
reason is shown below:

VirtualBox is complaining that the installation is incomplete. Please
run `VBoxManage --version` to see the error message which should contain
instructions on how to fix this error.
```

#### Then it follows with this error

```bsh
WARNING: The character device /dev/vboxdrv does not exist.
         Please install the virtualbox-dkms package and the appropriate
         headers, most likely linux-headers-azure.

         You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
6.1.16_Ubuntur140961
```

I have tried also running `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-azure` but still comes up with the same error.

Also when I run `modprobe vboxdrv` it throws the following error:
`modprobe: FATAL: Module vboxdrv not found in directory /lib/modules/5.4.0-1051-azure`

This is the Codespace setup:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Disable Secure Boot and try again.

Comment: I don't think this can happen on codespaces;

Comment: It happens is any UEFI hardware with Secure Boot enabled as it prevents unsigned drivers from loading, exactly the error you're getting.

Comment: It still gives me errors: EFI variables are not supported on this system